# ASP.NET, NSwag - How to generate models and controllers and run NSwag in one build

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, swagger, nswag

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project and trying to do the following steps in one build:

1. Generate models from an existing database with [Entity Framework scaffolding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold).
2. Generate controllers from the generated models with [ASP.NET Code generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-6.0#description).
3. Run [NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag) to generate swagger.json.

The problem is that every step requires that the project is built before it, so for example if new controllers are generated in a build, NSwag cannot use them as they are just there as source code, not built yet.

How could I run all the 3 steps in one build and get a correctly built result?

These are the build steps I currently have in my csproj file:

```
<Target Name="ScaffoldModels" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="Scripts/scaffold_models.bat" />
</Target>

<Target Name="ScaffoldControllers" AfterTargets="ScaffoldModels">
    <Exec Command="Scripts/scaffold_controllers.bat" />
</Target>

<Target Name="NSwag" AfterTargets="ScaffoldControllers">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Reference)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)References" />
    <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Net60) run nswag.json /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutDir)References" />
</Target>
```

scaffold_models.bat:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold name=MainDatabase Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --force --no-build --data-annotations --output-dir Application/Core/Models --context MainContext
```

scaffold_controllers.bat:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (Application/Core/Models/*) do (
    set classname=%%~nf
    dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator controller --force --restWithNoViews --dataContext Backend.Application.Core.Models.MainContext --controllerName !classname!Controller --model Backend.Application.Core.Models.!classname! --relativeFolderPath Application/Core/Controllers
)
endlocal
```